# Enabling http for a new mvc3 site on a server that does not have a ssl certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ssl, https

I've created a new site using mvc3 and now I'm getting closer to the point where I need to add `[RequireHttps]` to my controller actions.  If I do that I can not run my site anymore on my local machine `[localhost]` since I don't have an ssl certificate.

---

Also, our production server is hosted by another organization.  They will purchase and install the ssl to the production server.  After they do that are there any special steps I need to take to deploy and Https enabled mvc3 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to install a self certified Certificate.  There are instructions everywhere for each version of IIS.  I did not need to used IIS Express.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use IIS Express, which should install a self certified certificate.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/901/iis-express-faq/

Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. Left click on project (mvc3 project name) and go to properties tab
2. change "SSL Enabled" to True.

You can check SSL using the value provided in "SSL URl" for normal http use "URL".

Please take note that the HTTPS URL made like this usually use a port number above "40000" 
use of IIS Express is recommended.